# Data is not get from json file using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, rest

Here is my HTML file and JS file
I'm not getting any data's from the JSON file to the html file
Below I have HTML files and JS files:

```
<!Doctype html>
   <html ng-app>
   <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      alert("c");
function imagecontroller($http,$scope){
    alert("cd");
    $http.get('ytdata.json').success(function(ytdata) {
        alert("cdscdsc");
                $scope.data = ytdata;
    });
}  
   </script>
 <style type="text/css">
        li{list-style:none;float:left;padding:20px;}
     a{text-decoration:none;}
 </style>
</head>
          <body>
   <div ng-controller="imagecontroller">
     <ul> 
     <li ng-repeat="datum in data">
              <a>
             <img ng-src="{{datum.thumbUrl}}"/>
                    <br />Id : {{datum.id}} 
                        <br />Purchase : {{datum.Purchase}} 
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

This is my json file:

```
[
        {
            "id":"mobile.jpg",
            "thumbUrl":"image url",
            "Purchase":20000
        },
        {
            "id":"pendrive.jpg",
            "thumbUrl":"image url",
            "Purchase":400
        },
        {
            "id":"laptop.jpg",
            "thumbUrl":"image url",
            "Purchase":3833
        }

]
```

Please get me the output for this program

Thanks in advance

Comment: YOu never tell it to run your function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a working plunker of what you are trying to do](http://plnkr.co/edit/IDzRzO?p=preview):

**Controller**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.data = null;
  $http.get("data.json").success(function (data) {
    $scope.data = data;
  });
});
```

**View**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="datum in data">
      <a>
        <img ng-src="{{datum.thumbUrl}}" />
        <br />Id : {{datum.id}}
        <br />Purchase : {{datum.Purchase}}
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: iam having same code in my localhost but it's not working

Comment: No, you don't. You are not setting up your angular controller correctly. Please review the plunker I posted above for the proper way to declare angular modules.

Comment: actually my controller name is "Imagecontroller" I applied it in my html file and my js file